# Hibernate: Several tables of one entity -> inherit hibernate-mapping

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I have an entity from which i want to have several tables in my sql database.

For Example, I have the Java Class in which i have an collection of another Java Class

```
@Entity
class SqlEntity{
    @Id
    @Column(unique = true)
    private Date date = null;
    @Column
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE }, mappedBy = "CollectionData")
    private Collection<CollectionData> collectionData = new ArrayList<>();

    @Column(name="columNameX")
    int attributeX;
    @Column(name="columNamey")
    int attributeY;
    ...
}
```

And i want different Data in different Tables according to where the Data are from:
SQL_ENTITY_GERMANY,
SQL_ENTITY_USA,
SQL_ENTITY_UK,
...

I was able to accomplish this by writing an `xml-mapping`  for every table(before that I had only java annotations to map the entity).
But I had to write an complete mapping for every table like this:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="...SqlEntity" table="SQL_ENTITY_GERMANY"
        entity-name="SQL_ENTITY_GERMANY">

        <id name="date" type="date" column="date">
        </id>

        <property name="columnNameX" column="attributeX" type="int" />
        <property name="columnNameY" column="attributeY" type="int" />
        ...

        <bag name="collectionData" cascade="all">
            <key column="date" />
            <one-to-many class="COLLECTION_DATA_GERMANY" />
        </bag>
    </class>

    <class name="...collectionData" table="COLLECTION_DATA_GERMANY"
        entity-name="COLLECTION_DATA_GERMANY">

        <id name="id" type="long" column="id">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>

        <property name="columnNameX" column="attributeX" type="int" />
        <property name="columnNameY" column="attributeY" type="int" />
        ...
        <many-to-one name="collectionData" class="SQL_ENTITY_GERMANY"
            fetch="select">
            <column name="date" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

So if I want to change anything in one entity class (like adding members), i have to change it in every single `xml-mapping`, too.

So i thought it maybe possible to just inheritate the mapping, so that the annotations of the class are still guilty as long as i dont overwrite it.
I tried to google and search on stackoverflow on this topic, but i found only things about java classes inheritance.
Or is there another solution which could help me with this?

Comment: you can use `TABLE_PER_CLASS` inheritance mapping and have one Abstract collection data and several inheritances

Comment: @javaguest According to this: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tableperclass
table per class is for having one table for severall implementations. But I want the opposite, severall tables for one implementations. Or did i misunderstood the concept?

Comment: OK I think i know what you mean now. By using TABLE_PER_CLASS I dont have to map the members of the CollectionsData every time. Ok, i will try that. Thanks

Comment: With TABLE_PER_CLASS i have to create one class per table, which i wanted to avoid! I think it does not really help me!

Comment: well, I'm searching through and for, but the fact that your db is not normalized makes it difficult. do you have DBA access? can you alter your sql_entity?

Answer (score 0):

Since your database is non-normalized, the only way of achieving what you want is creating an abstract class and several concrete subclasses with appropriate country codes.

If you are able to alter a schema, I'd suggest adding a column `COUNTRY_CODE VARCHAR(2) NULL` to your `SQL_ENTITY` table, insert all data from your `SQL_ENTITY_*` tables.

You can do so by:

1)Creating a new `SQL_ENTITY` table

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_SQL_ENTITY (
id_entity INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
value1 VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL;
value2 VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL;
country_code VARCHAR(2) NULL;
)
```

2) Inserting the data from the other tables:

```
INSERT INTO NEW_SQL_ENTITY (value1,value2,country_code) VALUES
(SELECT value1,value2, 'UK' from SQL_ENTITY_UK)
```

3) Repeating for all `SQL_ENTITY` tables

Comment: But i had to create 2 subclasses for every table, right? One for the collectionData and one for the SqlEntity. Also i had to change in every subclass of the SqlEntity the CollectionData to the according Subclass type. I would like to work with the SqlEntity in the project not with the subclasses, because the content for every Country is exactly the same.

Comment: And yes, alternating the table would not be a problem.

Comment: yep, so i guess the best course of action would be to normalize the DB